# apt-mark showhold doesn't list all the packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I've held the following packages (on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
sudo apt-mark hold virtualbox
sudo apt-mark hold virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-mark hold virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
sudo apt-mark hold virtualbox-qt
```

but now when I want to list the held packages:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold

virtualbox
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
virtualbox-qt
```

one package is missing !
Why ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the package `virtualbox` depends on the package `virtualbox-dkms`,

When you hold the package `virtualbox`, it will automatically hold `virtualbox-dkms` because without `virtualbox-dkms`, `virtualbox` will not be able to run.

Edit: `apt-cache rdepends packagename` should do what you want. In your case, do `apt-cache rdepends virtualbox` should give you the output.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. 
But is there a way to show dependencies as well ?

Comment: Indeed, `apt-cache rdepends virtualbox` shows all dependencies but it doesn't show which ones are held.

Comment: Since `virtualbox` is held, all the dependencies shown using `apt-cache rdepends virtualbox` will also be hold. Holding `virtualbox` using `apt-mark` means all the dependencies are also held by `apt-mark`.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative you can use:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^h
```

to get a list of all packages with desired action of "hold".

This time nothing will be ignored.